# formidable Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: how it fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Server\node_modules\formidable\src\index.js from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Server\back\productController.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Server\back\productController.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Server\back\productController.js:5:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Server\server.js:15:27) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Node.js v18.16.1

How fix this?
I try to use import, but not working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both 'import' and 'require' in the same project.

This probably means that you are using 'require' in your code but the package is exported as an ES module which don't work with 'require', you have to 'import' it.
Since we cannot mesh 'import' and 'require' there are a few options:

1. Use '[formidable-serverless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-serverless)' - a mirror version of formidable that you can 'require' but it might be an older version (if that matters to you)
2. Convert all your 'require' statements to 'import' statements and you should have no issues with the regular 'fromidable'
3. There is a way to make both 'require' and 'import' statements work in the same file but it's a mess and it's not recommended, just search for 'nodejs using require in es module' if you are curious

Comment: I just install formidable v2 and it works